# ECCN for Automapper

Tags: automapper, automapper-3

I am building a C# VS2012 app that will be used overseas.  I have been using Automapper for years and would like to keep using it.  One stipulation handed to me is that all add-ons for my project outside of Microsoft must have a published ECCN (Export Control Classification Number). Microsoft has a [published ECCN](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/exporting/eccn.aspx) for .NET Framework 4.5 and Visual Studio 2013.  They are trusted for export.
I have been looking for a *published* ECCN for Automapper, and the closest thing I can find is this Google groups [article](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/automapper-users/MFLJ17cPMxM) where Jimmy Bogard personally responded that it is the same for .NET framework.  However, I have been asked for a *published* ECCN from Automapper that would state something official like this:

"The ECCN for Automapper is: [x]".

I have looked at the [Automapper GitHub Site](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) but couldn't find what I needed.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about export control or legal issues, not programming or software development.

Answer (score 2):

AutoMapper doesn't need an ECCN - it contains no encryption functionality.